# Django - How to get that an object attribute be automatically updated depending on the actual date?

Tags: python, django

I need that an object attribute be automatically updated past some puntual date and time. I have a class and a method within this class to try to perform this, but the issue here is that I need to call the method (or access a @property) to this be applied.
The code is something like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    status =  models.CharField()
    expiring_time = models.DateTimeField()

    def is_active(self):
        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        if date > self.expiring_time:
            self.status = "expired"
        self.save()
```

I found some similar questions but none of them seems to get the point that I'm looking for. I heard about celery to perform scheduled tasks, but as I understood this just be keep calling the method and is not the same that I'm looking for.

I would like to know if is there a way to keep this method "always active", or what could be a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem it practical to keep a method "always active". Either some other tool like cronjob or celery needs to keep calling it, or just do not store the value in database. You can use annotate to add status value to an object inside queryset using [**`conditional expression`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case), like this:

```
from django.db.models import Case, CharField, Value, When
foo = Foo.objects.annotate(
    is_active = Case(
        When(
            date__lte=datetime.now(), then=Value("expired")
        ),
        default=Value("not expired"),
        output_field=CharField()
    )
)

for val in foo:
   print(val.is_active)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe use the `post_init` signal inside your Model.

This signal is sent right after your instance has been initialized.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_init
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Foo(models.Model):
    status =  models.CharField()
    expiring_time = models.DateTimeField()

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def is_active(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    if date > instance.expiring_time:
        instance.status = "expired"
    instance.save()
```

**Caution** : this signal will executes this function each time the instance is returned ; even during a queryset iteration. It may cause performance issues.

Take a look to the doc : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-init

Another way would be to call this function each time you instanciate your Foo model. It will take your business logic outside of your Model.